# Error validating HTML through w3c validator

Tags: w3c-validation

I am trying to validate my site through the w3c validator, but am getting the following error:

```
Line 62, Column 393: & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)
…mysite.com/projects/bnd?page=catagory&id=10">asdas</a> (67)</li><li><a href="
```

I have fixed all other things, but using `&` in a URL is not a valid w3c URI. How then could I validate my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&amp;` like this:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/projects/bnd?page=catagory&amp;id=10">
```

Answer (score 0):

search and replace the `&` at line 62 with`&amp;`